# Prevent infinite loop on function component with default parameter and useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When creating a function component in React and setting a default parameter everything works like expected and the component will be rendered once. But as soon as you add a hook like `useEffect` and use this parameter in the dependency array the component rerenders forever.
I've created a simple demo here: https://codesandbox.io/s/infinite-useeffect-loop-on-default-value-tv7hj?file=/src/TestComponent.jsx

The reason is quite obvious, because when using an object as default parameter, it will be created again and will not be equal to the previous one. And of course this doesn't happen on primitive default parameter values like number or string.

Is there any better way to avoid this side effect besides using `defaultProps`?

Comment: Instead of listening for `[value]` in dependencies, you can use `[value.name]` in dependencies and since value.name always exists, should not be a problem for your case.

Comment: @ZameerHaque: Good idea. With this you set the dependency to a primitive type which works. This method can be used in some cases, but if you have to call another method inside the `useEffect` this may not work or you have to know which properties are used in this method and add all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, instead of setting the default value of `value` to being an object, just set it to false. Then check if `value` is truthy, if it is, then access the correct properties, otherwise, just show a default value. [New code](https://codesandbox.io/s/infinite-useeffect-loop-on-default-value-forked-5zsow?file=/src/TestComponent.jsx).

It would be something like:

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const TestComponent = ({ value = false }) => {
  const [calcValue, setCalcValue] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    setCalcValue((cur) => cur + 1);
  }, [value]);

  return (
    <div>
      {value ? value.name : "Test"}:{calcValue}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: This may work in some scenarios but it's not easy to maintain, because you're spreading the defaut object to many places inside the function component. But it's a valid workaround

Comment: That's a great point, especially if you have a lot of properties

Answer (score 1):

The reason you get infinite loops is because the reference of `value` keeps changing.

The first time the component is rendered, it sees a new reference to value, which triggers the `useEffect`, which in turns modifies the state of the component, and this leads to a new render, which causes `value` to be re-created once again because the old *reference* to that variable has changed.

The easiest way to deal with this is to just create a default value outside the component and use that (*basically the same as the `defaultProps` solution*):

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const defaultValue = {name: "Test"}; // <-- default here
const TestComponent = ({ value = defaultValue }) => {
  const [calcValue, setCalcValue] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    setCalcValue((cur) => cur + 1);
  }, [value]);

  return (
    <div>
      {value.name}:{calcValue}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Doing this will ensure that each time the component renders, it sees the same reference for `value`, therefore the `useEffect` hook only runs once.

---

Another way of dealing with this is to first wrap your component with [`memo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo), then create a new state variable which takes on the original `value`, and make your `useEffect` hook depend on this new state variable:

```
const TestComponent = React.memo(({ value = {name: "Test"} }) => {
  const [calcValue, setCalcValue] = useState(0);
  const [myValue, setMyValue] = useState(value);

  useEffect(() => {
    setCalcValue((cur) => cur + 1);
  }, [myValue]);

  return (
    <div>
      {myValue.name}:{calcValue}
    </div>
  );
});
```

The reason why we wrap the component with `memo` is so that it only re-renders after a state change **if** the prop had changed in *value* (instead of *reference*). You can change the way `memo` detects props changes by providing a custom comparison function as a second parameter.